# Permanently ignore winforms designer errors

Tags: c#, winforms, designer, generated

I have a C# project in which the generated designer code throws an error at design time. Fixing the error requires me to modify the generated code, which gets overwritten every time I build.

The error is the generic full screen "To prevent possible data loss before loading the designer..." I can "ignore and continue" each time, but I can't seem to find a way to ignore it permanently.

Comment: Could caused runtime errors ....

Answer (score 0):

Ignoring this permanently is highly dangerous and probably impossible. You'd be better served by determining the problem and fixing the bug in the offending control (assuming you are the author of that control -- if not, contact the author!).

Comment: I agree with you, but it would still be nice to know how to turn off the constant whining until I can figure out a real bugfix.